# Proof for range of mandelbrot set?

Tags: fractals

Really simple question, I'm aware that if the value of c used for the mandelbrot set ever gets more than 2 units away from the origin, the value will tend to infinity and it doesn't belong in the set. Is there any proof for this? How do we know that a value greater than 2 will always tend to infinity in the mandelbrot?

Comment: Are you familiar with how a value is determined to be in the set or not?

Comment: @abiessu Yes, using the Zn+1=Zn^2+c equation, if it doesn't tend to infinity, c is in the set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $|c| > 2$, then $f_c(c) = c^2 + c$ has absolute value at least $|c|^2 - |c| = |c|(|c| - 1) > |c|$.

Now, suppose that $|f^{n-1}_c(0)| > |f^{n-2}_c(0)|(|c| - 1)$ and $|f^{n-1}_c(0)| > |c|$ for some $n$.

Then \begin{align*}|f^n_c(0)| &= |f^{n-1}_c(0)^2 + c| \\&\geq |f_c^{n-1}(0)|^2 - |c| \\&> |f_c^{n-1}(0)|^2 - |f_c^{n-1}(0)| \\&= |f_c^{n-1}(0)|(|f_c^{n-1}(0)| - 1) \\&> |f_c^{n-1}(0)|(|c| - 1).\end{align*}

Thus, we inductively have $|f_c^n(0)| > (|c| - 1)|f_c^{n-1}(0)|$ for all $n$, and hence $|f_c^n(0)| > (|c| - 1)^{n-1}|f_c^1(0)| = (|c| - 1|)^{n-1}|c|$, which diverges to infinity, hence $|f_c^n(0)|$ similarly diverges to infinity.

Comment: Thanks for your response, very much appreciated. Quick clarification, how exactly can we be sure that fnc(c) has an absolute value of |c|(|c|−1)^n? It sort of makes sense but I can't entirely follow

Comment: Also is there a name for this proof? I'm gonna use it for a paper and I need to be able to cite it.

Comment: There was a slight mistake, will fix it now, sorry.

Comment: @TomasPremoliMuniagurria Fixed now: hopefully that makes it clearer. Not sure of a name, but at least the result is likely to be in any book on fractals, and nobody is going to object too much to you filling in the details of a proof that the book skims over.