# How to show that the sequence $z_n$ is unbounded if $|c|>2?$ $(z_0 = 0, z_{n+1} = z_n^2 + c)$.

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to show that the sequence $z_n$ is unbounded if $|c|>2$, but I can't find a nice way to do that. $(z_0 = 0, z_{n+1} = z_n^2 + c)$.

The only usable tool seems to be the reverse triangle inequality. By using that I've found that $|z_2|>|c|\epsilon$, where $\epsilon>1$ and that $|z_3|>|c|(|c|\epsilon^2-1)$. How to continue the argument is unclear.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3468273/42969 or https://math.stackexchange.com/q/424143/42969

Comment: Found [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%7Cc%7C%5Cge%202%24%2C%20AND%20content%3AMandelbrot)